# JavaFX: How to create an undo point on a codeArea

Tags: javafx, editor, undo, redo

I have a CodeArea (org.fxmisc.richtext.CodeArea). It support the hotkeys CTRL-Z for undo and CTRL-Y for redo.

I am inserting a text programmatically at the caret position.
Now when I hit undo, this undo goes further than undoing the text insertion, it undoes the creation of the file so that the code area is empty again.

I would like to create an undo save point before I insert the text.
There must be some way to do this (I hope!).

```
public void insertText(String text) 
{
    //TODO insert code here to create an undo point
    int index = codeArea.getCaretPosition();
    codeArea.insertText(index, text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [UndoManager:](https://fxmisc.github.io/undo/javadoc/1.3.1/org/fxmisc/undo/UndoManager.html?is-external=true)

```
public void insertText(String text) 
{
    codeArea.getUndoManager().mark();
    int index = codeArea.getCaretPosition();
    codeArea.insertText(index, text);
}
```